# How can I create an empty Pandas DataFrame with specific columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a DataFrame which is always initialized with the same columns, but sometimes doesn't have any data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = []
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

But this fails with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  …
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (0, 0), indices imply (3, 0)
```

How can I create an empty DataFrame with columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As of Pandas version 0.16.1](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/9939), passing `data = []` works:

```
In [85]: df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [86]: df
Out[86]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
```

For older versions of Pandas, don't pass any `data`:

```
In [69]: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [70]: df
Out[70]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
```

or pass `data=None`:

```
In [71]: df = pd.DataFrame(None, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [72]: df
Out[72]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
```

Comment: In the case that data do exist, then, is there a cleaner method than: `df = pd.DataFrame(data=(data if len(data) else None), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])` to set it?

Comment: There are only the usual tricks. Either use `if..else` statement, a conditional expression (as you show), or `try..except`.